# C - Segmentation fault with pointer to array

Tags: c

i'm hoping someone can help me with this little piece of code. It's a stupid test, but i dont know what is it that i am doing wrong. It's like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int **ipp;

int ventas [3][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};

int main(void){

    ipp = (int **)ventas;

    printf("%d\n", **ipp);

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles (I'm using GCC), but when I execute it I keep getting a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong? I think it has something to do with an un-initalized pointer, but 'ventas' is an array so it is already initialized, and it's assigned to **ipp.

Comment: Hint: Check the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have such casting like

```
ipp = (int **)ventas;
```

then the value of the variable is the address of the first element of the array `ventas`. In this case after dereferencing the pointer

```
*ipp
```

you get the value stored at this address. If to assume that `sizeof( int )` is equal to `sizeof( int * )` than the first element of the array equal to 1 is considered as a memory address. After applying second dereferencing

```
**ipp
```

you get memory access violation.

It will be correct to write either like

```
int ( *ipp )[4] = ventas;
```

and then

```
printf("%d\n", **ipp);
```

or like

```
int *ipp = ( int * )ventas;
```

and then

```
printf("%d\n", *ipp);
```

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to pointer and a 2D array are not interchangeable, change to:

```
int (*ipp)[4]; /* A pointer to an array of 4 ints */
...
ipp = ventas;
```

Comment: It appears that the OP wants a pointer to a 2D array. Anyway, for the purpose of printing the address, a pointer to a 2D array or a pointer to the first element will give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

- A pointer-to-pointer is not an array. Nor is it a pointer to a 2D array. They aren't the slightest compatible. Just forget about pointer-to-pointers in this case.
- If you want a pointer to a 2D array, you must write `int (*ipp)[3][4] = &ventas;`
- You can't print a pointer using `%d` format specifier. You should use `%p`.

Corrected code for printing the address of the 2D array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int ventas [3][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
  int (*ipp)[3][4];

  ipp = &ventas;
  printf("%p\n", ipp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%p\n", ipp);` should not be `printf("%p\n", (void*)ipp);` ?

Comment: @Michi Yes indeed, if we are picky.

Comment: strictly speaking, `printf("%p\n", ipp);` should be `printf("%p\n", (void *) ipp);`